# <input type=“file” /> file format validation not working if WINRAR is installed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate, winrar

As per my code validation functionality  should accept only ZIP version.

So its working on my 1st system all 3 browsers "IE 10, Chrome 29 and Firfox 24" and **with NO** WINRAR installed

But now I have some strange issue, my code was working fine till the time I didn't have WINRAR installed.On the other system where I have WINRAR installed I am getting issue, that if I upload the ZIP file also, on my second system, still it prompts the error that "It accepts ZIP file only"

Below is my code and the Fiddle too:

**JQUERY**

```
<script>

    $().ready(function () {

        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#deploymentUploadForm").validate({

            rules:{
                File: {
                    required: true,
                    accept: "application/zip,application/octet-stream,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed"
                }
            },

            messages:{
                File: {
                    required: "This field is mandatory!",
                    accept: "Accepts only zip file!"
                }
            }  

        });

    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="wizardSteps">
            <form action="~/Deployment/FileUpload" name="deploymentUploadForm" id="deploymentUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <h1>Deployment</h1>

                <p>
                    <input type="file" name="File" accept="application/zip">
                </p>

                <div role="button" class="marginTop50 marginBottom">
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" id="getDeploymentList" value="Upload" class="active" >
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/rMS8D/

I am getting the same issue fiddle too when I installed WINRAR in my 1st system (which was working fine beforer installing the WINRAR)

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: what mimetype does winRAR change the zip files to?

Comment: how to check that?? Even I am trying to find that too...

Comment: hmm. you can "upload" a zip at http://danml.com/slim/ , the resulting dataURL will be prefixed with the mime added by the browser/OS... the input says "Choose Files" in chrome...

Comment: I don't see any file upload option in this website... from where to upload?

Comment: it's next to the green "Swap In+Out" button. i guess i shouldn't have been so clever styling the input...

Comment: Got It... Thanks!!Now when I uploaded I got "data:application/zip;base64" but I have "application/zip" mime type added already

Comment: shoot. well, there goes my idea. maybe check for a browser plugin, addon, or extension that was silently added when winRar was installed. PS, i like 7Zip since it's free and cross platform...

Comment: Can you please also confirm is my fiddle working for you???

Comment: it tells me "413 Request Entity Too Large", but i don't have winZip...

Comment: possible duplicate of [<input type=“file” /> file format validation on different systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031804/input-type-file-file-format-validation-on-different-systems)

Comment: @Sparky: Did you find any solution on the post that you have mentioned?

Comment: Whether you've received an answer or not, you are not allowed to post the same question multiple times.

Comment: @dandavis: I was not able to find out what browser plugin, addon, or extension was being added with WinRar but, finally I found other method to validate which by detecting extension... so finally its working... thanks for looking!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling alot to find why the "accept:" method is not accepting zip file which is created by "WinRaR".. I changed the "accept" method with "extension" which is provided in "additional-methods.js" -- `<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>`. Please find the latest code below:

**JQUERY:**

```
<script>

    $().ready(function () {

        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#deploymentUploadForm").validate({

            rules:{
                File: {
                    required: true,
                    extension: "zip"
                }
            },

            messages:{
                File: {
                    required: "This field is mandatory!",
                    extension: "Accepts only zip file!"
                }
            }  

        });

    });
</script>
```

If you don't want to include the full "additional-methods.js" then below is the method:-

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("extension", function(value, element, param) {
  param = typeof param === "string" ? param.replace(/,/g, '|') : "png|jpe?g|gif";
  return this.optional(element) || value.match(new RegExp(".(" + param + ")$", "i"));
}, jQuery.format("Please enter a value with a valid extension."));
```

Thanks all for looking into the issue!